# Yocto - can not execute debug package

Tags: linux, yocto, openembedded

I was trying to install debug package of an application built by Yocto.

Aftre installation, the executables are found on `.debug` directory.

However, when I try to execute those I get the below error

```
-sh: /etc/.debug/app: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

file command displays :

```
file /etc/.debug/app
/etc/.debug/app: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter *empty*, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=1dfc051dc47683e0715b842998daadd4d12c541e, not stripped
```

arch command output is `armv7l`.

The app seems to be working fine [ the one with no debugg information].

And the `file` command on application is

```
file /etc/app
/etc/app: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=1dfc051dc47683e0715b842998daadd4d12c541e, stripped
```

What I want is to execute the application which is compiled using debug symbols, so that when the application crashes it gives `coredump`.

Is there a way to fix this or is there any other better method to run program using debug information [using Yocto framework ]  ?

Answer (score 1):

Debug packages contain *just* the debug symbols, you don't run them directly.  Run the standard executables, and gdb will read the symbols that the debug package installed.

Comment: I dont want to try running application from gdb. Running from gdb may reduce the performance in my case I think. Instead, would like to run the application and make it crash, so that it would generate the coredump file. Once I get the coredump file, I can analyse it later.

Comment: Just point gdb at the core dump, it will read the symbols from the debug package automatically.